# Is it possible to evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} x\sin(1/x)$ via L'Hospital?

Tags: calculus

> Is it possible to evaluate
>    $$\lim_{x \to 0} x\sin(1/x)$$ via **L'Hospital** rule?

Comment: why would someone do it like that? $\sin(x)$ is bounded and $x$ goes to $0$.

Comment: Why would you bother with L'Hospital? It's just a squeeze theorem problem and this is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: I believe squeeze approach will surely work. But, I want L'hospital

Comment: L'Hopital's rule only applies to indeterminate forms. Applying it to other limits leads to wrong answers.

Comment: I don't see the point, no matter what you do, after deriving you won't get a limit that is easier than this one.

Comment: The limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(1/x)$ doesnt exist. Generally L'Hopital is used for limits where it goes to indeterminated forms $0/0$ and $\infty/\infty$ with some restrictions. But this is not the case.

Comment: Forget LH! That should be the last resort to use.

Comment: He didn't say $x$ is real, maybe $x$ is complex.  Then you cannot say $\sin(1/x)$ is bounded, but in fact $\lim_{x\to 0} x\sin(1/x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use L'Hopital's rule for that.  I would **squeeze,** thus:
$$
-1 \le \sin(\text{anything at all}) \le 1.
$$
Therefore $\Big(x\cdot\sin(\text{something})\Big)$ is between $\pm x$.  Since $+x$ and $-x$ both approach $0$ as $x\to 0$, so does $\Big(x\cdot\sin(\text{something})\Big)$.

To use L'Hopital's rule you need a fraction in which the numerator and denominator either both approach $0$ or both approach $\infty$.  You have $x$ approaching $0$, but $\sin(1/x)$ does not approach any limit and neither does $1/\sin(1/x)$.